# Connecting to a sql server using java and tomcat 8

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, tomcat, jdbc

I have a SQL management server 2014 and a local tomcat ( ver 8 ).
I am trying to access my database locally.
I used a .udl file to create my connection string :

```
 Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=****;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=trip;Data Source=PROJ-1161\SQLEXPRESS
```

In addition, I'm using the following code to load up the drivers: (tried different ones, non seemed to work currectly)

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

When the my program reaches that area within the code it throws the following exception :

```
26-Jun-2016 16:33:03.904 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring-mvc'
26-Jun-2016 16:33:04.249 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
26-Jun-2016 16:33:04.249 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
26-Jun-2016 16:47:07.096 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
26-Jun-2016 16:47:07.096 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
26-Jun-2016 16:47:27.255 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
26-Jun-2016 16:47:27.918 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring-mvc'
26-Jun-2016 16:47:32.905 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring-mvc'
26-Jun-2016 16:47:33.119 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
26-Jun-2016 16:47:33.119 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
26-Jun-2016 16:48:00.970 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
26-Jun-2016 16:48:00.970 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
26-Jun-2016 16:48:07.261 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
26-Jun-2016 16:48:07.966 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring-mvc'
26-Jun-2016 16:48:16.751 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [spring-mvc] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=****;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=trip;Data Source=PROJ-1161\SQLEXPRESS] with root cause
 java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=****;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=trip;Data Source=PROJ-1161\SQLEXPRESS
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at org.bgu.ise.ddb.registration.RegistarationController.getAllLocations(RegistarationController.java:221)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When I searched online for the answer, I have seen many say that I might be missing DLLs/JARs, I downloaded a lot, but nothing made it work so far.

Does anyone knows how to solve this one ? 
Thanks !

Comment: Do you have the Microsoft JDBC driver included in your classpath?

Comment: Yes, already included it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL string must be `jdbc:sqlserver://PROJ-1161\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=trip;user=sa;password=****`

Here are the details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Tried different variations of that string, but yours worked !! thanks a lot !